# Can't use the column letter in QUERY in Google sheet

Tags: sql, database, google-sheets

I have two Google sheets. I use one of them as a source of data, and the second one for making queries. I import the data using `IMPORTRANGE`. Everything works fine with me except that I cannot use the column names (A, B, C, etc.).

If I used letters an error is returned from the query. If I use Col1 Col2 instead of the letters, it works. This is confusing me. How can I use my source sheet letters in an easy way (I found some solutions online using MATCH function which will make the query to complicated and I don't want that).

Note that the letters in the current query are for cells in the same sheet (not the source sheet that I cannot use its columns letters).

Here is my query:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("[source_sheet_url]","sheetname!A1:X100"), "SELECT count(Col1) where Col1='"&B3&"' and (Col5 ='"&$A$5&"' or Col5='"&$A$6&"') and Col6 contains '"&$A$17&"' label count(Col1) ''")
```

Comment: When you are pulling data via importrange() the source data has `no longer a valid range` (like A:X); so you cannot call them out via column letters and instead had to use the relative column number per se.,

Comment: @rockinfreakshow In the same query I used A1:X100 (letters) to specify the cells I want to pull?!

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify/expand on Rockinfreakshow's comment, if you supply anything other than a range reference to the *data* argument of QUERY, you can no longer refer to columns within the select string by letter, because computed arrays don't belong to a sheet so their columns can't be referred to by reference to their location within a sheet. You might find this surprising behaviour in the context of IMPORTRANGE, but it is a function so its output is a computed array like any other function capable of outputting an array.

If you moved your data source to a separate tab in the same sheet as your QUERY tab, you could use column letters as you'd then be able to refer to the data range as a range reference.